# There is quite a bit of space between the two sections, How to figure it out?

Tags: html, css

Here I have created a website, where my restaurant menu is displayed.  My menu is divided into several sections, the website is working fine but there is quite a bit of white space between each section.  I can't figure out how to delete that blank space, I've tried many ways and even tried Chat GPT, but it still doesn't work.  I want each menu to be side by side without the white space and empty space that it contains

```css
  .name h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  /* Adjust this value to control the spacing */
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #00a60e;
  /* Initial background color */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.name h2:hover {
  background-color: #de4300;
  /* Change color on hover */
}

.name h2.active {
  background-color: #004dab;
  /* Change color when clicked */
}

.name ul {
  display: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  user-select: none;
}

header {
  background-color: #003333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

section {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}

section.active {
  display: block;
}

h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  background-color: #001a4d;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.name {
  color: #ffffff;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Candara';
}

.price {
  color: #00ff00;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.quantity-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.quantity {
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.add-button {
  background-color: #ff3300;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.remove-button {
  background-color: #FF6347;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#selected-items {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#selected-items h2 {
  color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

#selected-items-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: ;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: calc(100%);
  margin: 0px;
}

#selected-items-list li {
  flex: 0 0 48%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#selected-items-list li span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#grand-total-box {
  border: 1px solid #004d00;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background-color: #ccfff5;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#total-amount {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #004d00, 0 0 5px #00ff00;
}

#grand-total-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#grand-total-box p {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #e04aa2, 0 0 5px #f55bb5;
  .name h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .name h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .name h2:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
  }
  .name h2.active {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
  }
  .name ul {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/KzzTRXnx/1.png" alt="Restaurant Image" style="width: 100%; max-width: 1000px; height: 160px; margin: 10px auto; display: block;">
  <h1>Menu</h1>
</header>
<section id="Starter" class="name active">
  <h2>Starter</h2>
  <ul>
    <li id="French Fry">
      <span class="name">French Fry</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹80.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-French-Fry" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('French Fry', 80, 'quantity-French-Fry')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="Paneer-Pokada">
      <span class="name">Paneer Pokada[6 Pcs]</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹160.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Paneer-Pokada" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Paneer Pokada[6 Pcs]', 160, 'quantity-Paneer-Pokada')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section id="Special Starter" class="name active">
  <h2>Special Starter</h2>
  <ul>
    <li id="Crispy Chilli Baby corn">
      <span class="name">Crispy Chilli Baby corn</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹150.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Crispy Chilli Baby corn" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Crispy Chilli Baby corn', 150, 'quantity-Crispy Chilli Baby corn')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="Chicken In BBQ Sauce">
      <span class="name">Chicken In BBQ Sauce [6 Pcs]</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹160.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Chicken-In-BBQ-Sauce" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chicken In BBQ Sauce [6 Pcs]', 160, 'quantity-Chicken-In-BBQ-Sauce')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section id="Soup" class="name active">
  <h2>Soup</h2>
  <ul>
    <li id="Hot-and-Sour-Soup">
      <span class="name">Hot & Sour Soup</span>
      <span class="price">₹80.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Hot-and-Sour-Soup" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Hot & Sour Soup', 80, 'quantity-Hot-and-Sour-Soup')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="Manchaw-Soup">
      <span class="name">Manchaw Soup</span>
      <span class="price">₹80.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Manchaw-Soup" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Manchaw Soup', 80, 'quantity-Manchaw-Soup')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section id="Tandoor Se" class="name active">
  <h2>Tandoor Se</h2>
  <ul>
    <li id="Chicken-Tangdi-Kabab">
      <span class="name">Chicken Tangdi Kabab (LEG)</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹130.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Chicken-Tangdi-Kabab" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chicken Tangdi Kabab (LEG)', 130, 'quantity-Chicken-Tangdi-Kabab')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="Chicken-Hariyali-Kabab">
      <span class="name">Chicken Hariyali Kabab [6 Pcs]</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹170.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Chicken-Hariyali-Kabab" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chicken Hariyali Kabab [6 Pcs]', 170, 'quantity-Chicken-Hariyali-Kabab')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section id="Noodles" class="name active">
  <h2>Noodles</h2>
  <ul>
    <li id="Hakka-Noodles-Veg">
      <span class="name">Hakka Noodles Veg</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹55.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Hakka-Noodles-Veg" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Hakka Noodles Veg', 55, 'quantity-Hakka-Noodles-Veg')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="Hakka-Noodles-Egg">
      <span class="name">Hakka Noodles Egg</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹65.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Hakka-Noodles-Egg" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Hakka Noodles Egg', 65, 'quantity-Hakka-Noodles-Egg')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section id="Chinese Main Course" class="name active">
  <h2>Chinese Main Course</h2>
  <ul>
    <li id="Chilly-Paneer-Gravy">
      <span class="name">Chilly Paneer Gravy [6 Pcs]</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹160.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Chilly-Paneer-Gravy" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chilly Paneer Gravy [6 Pcs]', 160, 'quantity-Chilly-Paneer-Gravy')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="Chilli-Chicken-Gravy">
      <span class="name">Chilli Chicken Gravy [6 Pcs]</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹130.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Chilli-Chicken-Gravy" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chilli Chicken Gravy [6 Pcs]', 130, 'quantity-Chilli-Chicken-Gravy')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<div id="selected-items">
  <h2>Selected Items</h2>
  <ul id="selected-items-list"></ul>
  <div id="grand-total-box">
    <p>Grand Total:₹</p>
    <div id="total-amount"><span id="total-amount-value">0.00</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My manual for flexbox is: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ 

Answer (score 0):

The blank space between your elements is margin which is set by default on h2 elements. You can add `margin: 0;` to your global h2 CSS rule.

```
h2 {
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;}
```

And I would recommend you to use developer tools in your browser. press 'F12 or 'right click->inspect' (for chrome). By inspecting the element you can see that you have some unwanted margins set on h2.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Restaurant Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    .name h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    /* Adjust this value to control the spacing */
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #00a60e;
    /* Initial background color */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  
  .name h2:hover {
    background-color: #de4300;
    /* Change color on hover */
  }
  
  .name h2.active {
    background-color: #004dab;
    /* Change color when clicked */
  }
  
  .name ul {
    display: none;
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  header {
    background-color: #003333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  
  section.active {
    display: block;
  }
  
  h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  li {
    background-color: #001a4d;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .name {
    color: #ffffff;
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Candara';
  }
  
  .price {
    color: #00ff00;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  
  .quantity-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .quantity {
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .add-button {
    background-color: #ff3300;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .remove-button {
    background-color: #FF6347;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  img {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  #selected-items {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  #selected-items h2 {
    color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  }
  
  #selected-items-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: ;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: calc(100%);
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  #selected-items-list li {
    flex: 0 0 48%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  #selected-items-list li span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  
  #grand-total-box {
    border: 1px solid #004d00;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    background-color: #ccfff5;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  
  #total-amount {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px #004d00, 0 0 5px #00ff00;
  }
  
  #grand-total-box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  #grand-total-box p {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px #e04aa2, 0 0 5px #f55bb5;
    .name h2 {
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .name h2 {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .name h2:hover {
      background-color: #e0e0e0;
    }
    .name h2.active {
      background-color: #d3d3d3;
    }
    .name ul {
      display: none;
    }
</style>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/KzzTRXnx/1.png" alt="Restaurant Image" style="width: 100%; max-width: 1000px; height: 160px; margin: 10px auto; display: block;">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
  </header>
  <section id="Starter" class="name active">
    <h2>Starter</h2>
    <ul>
      <li id="French Fry">
        <span class="name">French Fry</span>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
        <span class="price">₹80.00</span>
        <div class="quantity-container">
          <input type="number" id="quantity-French-Fry" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
          <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('French Fry', 80, 'quantity-French-Fry')">Add</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="Paneer-Pokada">
        <span class="name">Paneer Pokada[6 Pcs]</span>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
        <span class="price">₹160.00</span>
        <div class="quantity-container">
          <input type="number" id="quantity-Paneer-Pokada" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
          <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Paneer Pokada[6 Pcs]', 160, 'quantity-Paneer-Pokada')">Add</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section id="Special Starter" class="name active">
    <h2>Special Starter</h2>
    <ul>
      <li id="Crispy Chilli Baby corn">
        <span class="name">Crispy Chilli Baby corn</span>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
        <span class="price">₹150.00</span>
        <div class="quantity-container">
          <input type="number" id="quantity-Crispy Chilli Baby corn" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
          <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Crispy Chilli Baby corn', 150, 'quantity-Crispy Chilli Baby corn')">Add</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="Chicken In BBQ Sauce">
        <span class="name">Chicken In BBQ Sauce [6 Pcs]</span>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
        <span class="price">₹160.00</span>
        <div class="quantity-container">
          <input type="number" id="quantity-Chicken-In-BBQ-Sauce" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
          <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chicken In BBQ Sauce [6 Pcs]', 160, 'quantity-Chicken-In-BBQ-Sauce')">Add</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section id="Soup" class="name active">
    <h2>Soup</h2>
    <ul>
      <li id="Hot-and-Sour-Soup">
        <span class="name">Hot & Sour Soup</span>
        <span class="price">₹80.00</span>
        <div class="quantity-container">
          <input type="number" id="quantity-Hot-and-Sour-Soup" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
          <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Hot & Sour Soup', 80, 'quantity-Hot-and-Sour-Soup')">Add</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="Manchaw-Soup">
        <span class="name">Manchaw Soup</span>
        <span class="price">₹80.00</span>
        <div class="quantity-container">
          <input type="number" id="quantity-Manchaw-Soup" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
          <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Manchaw Soup', 80, 'quantity-Manchaw-Soup')">Add</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section id="Tandoor Se" class="name active">
    <h2>Tandoor Se</h2>
    <ul>
      <li id="Chicken-Tangdi-Kabab">
        <span class="name">Chicken Tangdi Kabab (LEG)</span>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
        <span class="price">₹130.00</span>
        <div class="quantity-container">
          <input type="number" id="quantity-Chicken-Tangdi-Kabab" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
          <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chicken Tangdi Kabab (LEG)', 130, 'quantity-Chicken-Tangdi-Kabab')">Add</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="Chicken-Hariyali-Kabab">
        <span class="name">Chicken Hariyali Kabab [6 Pcs]</span>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
        <span class="price">₹170.00</span>
        <div class="quantity-container">
          <input type="number" id="quantity-Chicken-Hariyali-Kabab" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
          <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chicken Hariyali Kabab [6 Pcs]', 170, 'quantity-Chicken-Hariyali-Kabab')">Add</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section id="Noodles" class="name active">
    <h2>Noodles</h2>
    <ul>
      <li id="Hakka-Noodles-Veg">
        <span class="name">Hakka Noodles Veg</span>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
        <span class="price">₹55.00</span>
        <div class="quantity-container">
          <input type="number" id="quantity-Hakka-Noodles-Veg" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
          <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Hakka Noodles Veg', 55, 'quantity-Hakka-Noodles-Veg')">Add</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="Hakka-Noodles-Egg">
        <span class="name">Hakka Noodles Egg</span>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
        <span class="price">₹65.00</span>
        <div class="quantity-container">
          <input type="number" id="quantity-Hakka-Noodles-Egg" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
          <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Hakka Noodles Egg', 65, 'quantity-Hakka-Noodles-Egg')">Add</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section id="Chinese Main Course" class="name active">
    <h2>Chinese Main Course</h2>
    <ul>
      <li id="Chilly-Paneer-Gravy">
        <span class="name">Chilly Paneer Gravy [6 Pcs]</span>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
        <span class="price">₹160.00</span>
        <div class="quantity-container">
          <input type="number" id="quantity-Chilly-Paneer-Gravy" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
          <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chilly Paneer Gravy [6 Pcs]', 160, 'quantity-Chilly-Paneer-Gravy')">Add</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="Chilli-Chicken-Gravy">
        <span class="name">Chilli Chicken Gravy [6 Pcs]</span>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
        <span class="price">₹130.00</span>
        <div class="quantity-container">
          <input type="number" id="quantity-Chilli-Chicken-Gravy" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
          <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chilli Chicken Gravy [6 Pcs]', 130, 'quantity-Chilli-Chicken-Gravy')">Add</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <div id="selected-items">
    <h2>Selected Items</h2>
    <ul id="selected-items-list"></ul>
    <div id="grand-total-box">
      <p>Grand Total:₹</p>
      <div id="total-amount"><span id="total-amount-value">0.00</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change the `<h2` to a `<div` and give it a class, same with the `<ul` give them a class not an element name in the CSS otherwise you find yourself fighting element names with "use".

I also rearranged the CSS to be more "top down" with body first etc.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  user-select: none;
}

header {
  background-color: #003333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

.name .menu-header {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #00a60e;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.name .menu-header:hover {
  background-color: #de4300;
}

.name .menu-header.active {
  background-color: #004dab;
}

.name .menu-list {
  display: none;
}

section {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}

section.active {
  display: block;
}

.menu-header {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-list li {
  background-color: #001a4d;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.name {
  color: #ffffff;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Candara';
}

.price {
  color: #00ff00;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.quantity-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.quantity {
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.add-button {
  background-color: #ff3300;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.remove-button {
  background-color: #FF6347;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#selected-items {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#selected-items h2 {
  color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

#selected-items-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: ;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: calc(100%);
  margin: 0px;
}

#selected-items-list li {
  flex: 0 0 48%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#selected-items-list li span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#grand-total-box {
  border: 1px solid #004d00;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background-color: #ccfff5;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#total-amount {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #004d00, 0 0 5px #00ff00;
}

#grand-total-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#grand-total-box p {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #e04aa2, 0 0 5px #f55bb5;
  .name .menu-header {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .name .menu-header {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .name .menu-header:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
  }
  .name .menu-header.active {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
  }
  .name .menu-list {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/KzzTRXnx/1.png" alt="Restaurant Image" style="width: 100%; max-width: 1000px; height: 160px; margin: 10px auto; display: block;">
  <h1>Menu</h1>
</header>
<section id="Starter" class="name active">
  <div class="menu-header">Starter</div>
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li id="French Fry">
      <span class="name">French Fry</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹80.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-French-Fry" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('French Fry', 80, 'quantity-French-Fry')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="Paneer-Pokada">
      <span class="name">Paneer Pokada[6 Pcs]</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹160.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Paneer-Pokada" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Paneer Pokada[6 Pcs]', 160, 'quantity-Paneer-Pokada')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section id="Special Starter" class="name active">
  <div class="menu-header">Special Starter</div>
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li id="Crispy Chilli Baby corn">
      <span class="name">Crispy Chilli Baby corn</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹150.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Crispy Chilli Baby corn" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Crispy Chilli Baby corn', 150, 'quantity-Crispy Chilli Baby corn')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="Chicken In BBQ Sauce">
      <span class="name">Chicken In BBQ Sauce [6 Pcs]</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹160.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Chicken-In-BBQ-Sauce" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chicken In BBQ Sauce [6 Pcs]', 160, 'quantity-Chicken-In-BBQ-Sauce')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section id="Soup" class="name active">
  <div class="menu-header">Soup</div>
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li id="Hot-and-Sour-Soup">
      <span class="name">Hot & Sour Soup</span>
      <span class="price">₹80.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Hot-and-Sour-Soup" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Hot & Sour Soup', 80, 'quantity-Hot-and-Sour-Soup')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="Manchaw-Soup">
      <span class="name">Manchaw Soup</span>
      <span class="price">₹80.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Manchaw-Soup" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Manchaw Soup', 80, 'quantity-Manchaw-Soup')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section id="Tandoor Se" class="name active">
  <div class="menu-header">Tandoor Se</div>
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li id="Chicken-Tangdi-Kabab">
      <span class="name">Chicken Tangdi Kabab (LEG)</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹130.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Chicken-Tangdi-Kabab" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chicken Tangdi Kabab (LEG)', 130, 'quantity-Chicken-Tangdi-Kabab')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="Chicken-Hariyali-Kabab">
      <span class="name">Chicken Hariyali Kabab [6 Pcs]</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹170.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Chicken-Hariyali-Kabab" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chicken Hariyali Kabab [6 Pcs]', 170, 'quantity-Chicken-Hariyali-Kabab')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section id="Noodles" class="name active">
  <div class="menu-header">Noodles</div>
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li id="Hakka-Noodles-Veg">
      <span class="name">Hakka Noodles Veg</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹55.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Hakka-Noodles-Veg" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Hakka Noodles Veg', 55, 'quantity-Hakka-Noodles-Veg')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="Hakka-Noodles-Egg">
      <span class="name">Hakka Noodles Egg</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹65.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Hakka-Noodles-Egg" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Hakka Noodles Egg', 65, 'quantity-Hakka-Noodles-Egg')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section id="Chinese Main Course" class="name active">
  <div class="menu-header">Chinese Main Course</div>
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li id="Chilly-Paneer-Gravy">
      <span class="name">Chilly Paneer Gravy [6 Pcs]</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹160.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Chilly-Paneer-Gravy" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chilly Paneer Gravy [6 Pcs]', 160, 'quantity-Chilly-Paneer-Gravy')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="Chilli-Chicken-Gravy">
      <span class="name">Chilli Chicken Gravy [6 Pcs]</span>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
      <span class="price">₹130.00</span>
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <input type="number" id="quantity-Chilli-Chicken-Gravy" class="quantity-input quantity" min="0" value="0">
        <button class="add-button" onclick="addItem('Chilli Chicken Gravy [6 Pcs]', 130, 'quantity-Chilli-Chicken-Gravy')">Add</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<div id="selected-items">
  <h2>Selected Items</h2>
  <ul class="menu-list" id="selected-items-list"></ul>
  <div id="grand-total-box">
    <p>Grand Total:₹</p>
    <div id="total-amount"><span id="total-amount-value">0.00</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<h2>` elements have semantic meaning that are important for a number of things, including accessibility. Additionally, according to the HTML spec, `<section>` elements should almost always have a corresponding heading element. Changing headings to divs to get rid of margins isn't a good solution.

Comment: @Sean Potentially not the most optimal solution, somewhat depends on use intent and if they are only being used to resize text.  Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements#usage_notes

Comment: Also a few other things that might impact accessibility such as no `alt=""` on `<img`, Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attributes Not putting a `type="button"` on the buttons ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#notes  OR the text of only "Add" rather than add the food item name, things like that.

Comment: It's clear their intent is as section headings for portions of the menu, and so they should remain heading elements.